# WHMCS MySQL and another MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, whmcs

We have a batch processing script that performs somewhat these operations

1. fetch data from the WHMCS database
2. for each rows; if rows needs processing

   1. connect to data's specified external MySQL database (remote server)
   2. fetch and process related data
   3. close distant connection
   4. update WHMCS database
3. ...

Now, while this is trivial, it breaks after the first row at step 2.4, because WHMCS does not specify a resource link for it's queries, and establishing a second mysql connection breaks the default WHMCS queries. A **simple code** shows what I mean :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE condition");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $conn = mysql_connect($row['mysql_host'], $row['mysql_user'], $row['mysql_pass']);
   ...
   mysql_close($conn);

   mysql_query("UPDATE sometable SET lastrun=NOW() WHERE id={$row['id']}");
}
```

The second call to `mysql_query` and also the one to `mysql_fetch_assoc` at the second iteration will both fail.

Is there  a way to "restore" the previous connection so it doesn't break? Please, do not suggest to use the `$whmcsmysql` resource link everywhere, this is not an viable option as I can not modify the encrypted WHMCS source code to do so, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're connecting to the same server every time, move the mysql_connection and mysql_close to outside of the while block, you don't need to keep connecting and disconnecting for every query.

Otherwise, open a separate connection to the WHMCS database (I don't know what WHMCS is), and specify which connection you're using in your calls to mysql_query.

```
$WHMCSConn = mysql_connect($user, $host, $pass);

$uniqueResultVariable = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE condition", $WHMCSConn);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($uniqueResultVariable)) {
   $conn = mysql_connect($row['mysql_host'], $row['mysql_user'], $row['mysql_pass']);
   ...
   mysql_query($someQuery, $conn);
   ...
   mysql_close($conn);

   mysql_query("UPDATE sometable SET lastrun=NOW() WHERE id={$row['id']}", $WHMCSConn);
}
mysql_close($WHMCSConn);
```

Also, I'm sure someone is going to leave a PDO/mysqli lecture here sooner or later.

Comment: I would gladly use PDO (but not mysqli) or some other OO DB class, but this is WHMCS (http://whmcs.com/) and how it is coded internally. As for the second connection, it may be different for every row, and there is no guarantee that it will be the same, thus opening it and closing it. Since the script is executed as a cron job (php-cli), I don't mind the extra time it takes to establish the db connection for every row, even if the same connection is made for more than one row in a row. Regardless, what you are suggesting still fails when entering the second iteration with mysql_fetch_assoc...

Comment: Could be two things, you should specify the $WHMCSConn in the initial mysql_query(), which I edited above.  Second, is it possible that you're rewriting the $result variable?  If so, just rename it in the mysql_fetch_assoc() part, which I've also edited above.

Comment: I'll be closing this question now. In the end, I managed to find the connection information, and after opening a new connection to the tier MySQL, I just used a persistent connection with the found connection information to "restore" the previous default connection. It works... Thanks for your input.